# What permission Required from DB :Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 required to make Bulk Insert from .NET using SqlBulkCopy

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlbulkcopy

What exact minimum permission Required from DB :Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 required to make Bulk Insert from .NET using SqlBulkCopy.

If not required to give full access on DB, can it be done for a specific table.

IS bulkadmin the answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What permission do I need to use SqlBulkCopy in SQL Server 2008?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/655293/what-permission-do-i-need-to-use-sqlbulkcopy-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: I stil dont have a clear reply on it